# How do I using the shell command "input keyevent 3" in a activity to return home page

Tags: android

Fist I used the shell command in terminal, it worked. But when I used that command in a activity, It didn't work. Then I used the command in a service, It didn't work. I checked the log and found it sent the keyevent 3(return home page command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fire an intent not inject input events. From the shell you can execute

```
$ am start -c android.intent.category.HOME -a android.intent.action.MAIN
```

or from your code use a similar intent with [startActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29).